# security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException

Tags: java, hadoop

I'm trying to run the MapRedure MaxTemperaute App and I'm getting this error:

```
"ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:yosr cause:java.io.IOException: Failed to set permissions of path: \tmp\hadoop-yosr\mapred\staging\yosr1581500197\.staging to 0700
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Failed to set permissions of path: \tmp\hadoop-yosr\mapred\staging\yosr1581500197\.staging to 0700"
```

I'm running it on eclipse on windows and the hadoop configuration is on a VM centOS
How can I resolve this

Comment: Please verify your hdfs directory permision. Set it to 777 and re run.

Comment: I disabled the hdfs security I don't need it for the moment, I added this to hdfs-site.xml:
<property>
    <name>dfs.permissions</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
I still get the error